# Cypher query for creating and linking nodes from a csv file

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a csv file generated with contents as follows

```
GOID            GOName                   
GO:0007190      activation of adenylate cyclase activity    



DiseaseID       DiseaseName

D058490     46 XY Disorders of Sex Development  

D000172     Acromegaly  

D049913     ACTH-Secreting,Pituitary Adenoma    

D058186     Acute Kidney Injury 

D000310     Adrenal Gland Neoplasms 

D000312     Adrenal Hyperplasia Congenital  

C537045     Albright's hereditary osteodystrophy    

D000544     Alzheimer Disease   

D019969     Amphetamine-Related Disorders   

D000855     Anorexia    

D000860     Anoxia  

D001008     Anxiety Disorders   

D001169     Arthritis Experimental  

D001171     Arthritis Juvenile  

D001172     Arthritis Rheumatoid    

D001249     Asthma  

D001254     Astrocytoma
```

and so on. 
I want to create link between GOIDs through Diseases such that one disease node is connected to two or more different GOID nodes.

My output should look like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Load your diseases all at once as under a :Disease label.
2. Load all your Global data at once under a :Global label
3. Create another CSV file with the Global->Disease linkages, and use MERGE to create the relationships.

The relationship CSV would look like this:

```
goID,diseaseID
"GO:1234","D000456"
```

The command to read the CSV and create the relationships would look like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/D:/Relationships.csv" as line 
MERGE (:Global  {goID: line.goID})-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(:Disease {diseaseID: line.diseaseID})
```

once your data is loaded, you can then query it like so:

```
MATCH (g:Global {goID: "GO:0007190"})-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(d:Disease)
return g, r, d
```

For cases where a disease has multiple global conditions, you can find and create a relationship like so:

```
match (d:Disease) 
match (go1:GO)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(d)
match (go2:GO)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(d) where go2 <> go1
create (go1)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(go2)
create (go2)-[:RELATIONSHIP]->(go1)
```

Strictly speaking you don't need a bi-directional relationship, so creating the second relationship could be left out. One potential concern is if more than one disease links two global values. If that is a concern, then setting a "Disease" property on the relationship would help identify how these globals are related.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your help my output shows ---> Added 9234 labels, created 9234 nodes, created 4617 relationships, statement executed in 244681 ms    but it is not showing output in graphical form. Should I fire any Match queries....???

Comment: LOAD CSV is about getting the data into your database. Once that's done, then you use MATCH() to query that data and get your graphs. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks Tim for your help but when i fire MATCH() query then output shows --> (no rows) any help??

Comment: Try this instead - it's a generic search that'll be restricted to 10 rows being returned. MATCH (g:Global)-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->(d:Disease)
return g, r, d limit 10

Comment: hi Tim sorry for late reply the queries are working fine just the part is relationship between a particular goID and Disease is returned but no connection in common is returned. for example if disease ID:1235 is linked with GO:1268499 and GO:2891792 then graph must represent the connectivity between both of them and the disease as well....is there any cypher query that can give this collective result.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a way to create the relationship you're looking for.

Comment: Also, if this helped you, pls mark it as an answer and upvote it. Thx!